# How to add button to NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

I want to add button like this one to share tweet: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPtpd.jpg)

Here is what I would like to call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to the `UINavigationItem` like this:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    
    UIImage *hearthImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart" inBundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:hearthImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(tapButton:)];
}

- (void) tapButton: (id) sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=YOUR_TEXT_HERE"]]];
}
```